# Count number of times in a row strings appear in a vector, then removing them if count is below a Threshold

Tags: java, vector, noise

I am currently trying to remove the "noise" from a Vector and Can't find an elegant way to do it. I currently have a Vector of strings, and another vector representing the number of times in a row those strings occur.

For some reason I just can't seem to get it working. The method I created to do this is shown below.

```
public static void correctDisturbance(Vector<String> names, Vector<Integer> lengths, int lengthGuard){

    int guard = lengths.size();

    int total = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < guard; i++)
    {
        if(lengths.elementAt(i) <= lengthGuard)
        {
            int newTotal = total + lengths.elementAt(i);

            while(total < newTotal)
            {
                System.out.println("Removing: " + names.elementAt(newTotal));
                names.removeElementAt(newTotal);
                newTotal--;
            }
            lengths.removeElementAt(i);
            guard--;
        }
        else
        {
            total += lengths.elementAt(i);
        }
    }
```

It removes some of the ones I need but not others. I have the threshold set to 5.

An example of the contents of the lengths vector is this: 
[15, 15, 1, 15, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 5, 1, 4, 1, 1, 3]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why do you need a separate vector for all the run lengths? It would probably be easier if you did it all in one go: keeping track of state would definitely be simpler.

Comment: Just finished a massive re-write of a couple of methods and it's working the way I want now, I was just really over-complicating things, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Use a Hash instead of a Vector to keep the count. The key is the line and the value is the count.

And btw use ArrayList instead Vector, if you need you can make it thread safe.

Comment: Do you mean the key is the string? If I have a string that occurs in two different sequences, fot example it is the first sequence of 15, and then the sequence of 3, I want to be able to keep the 15 and remove the 3. Will this cause a problem if they are both the same key?

Answer (score 0):

There was very little wrong with your method. Here is the debugged version:

```
public static void correctDisturbance(List<String> names,
        List<Integer> lengths, int lengthGuard) {
    int guard = lengths.size();
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0;i < guard;i++) {
        if (lengths.get(i) <= lengthGuard) {
            int newTotal = total + lengths.get(i);
            while( total < newTotal ) {
                newTotal--; // LINE MOVED
                System.out.println("Removing: " + names.get(newTotal));
                names.remove(newTotal);
            }
            lengths.remove(i);
            i--; // LINE ADDED
            guard--;
        } else {
            total += lengths.get(i);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see only two changes were required. First the `newTotal` had to be decremented before used because Java arrays and lists are zero based. Second when you removed an item from the `lengths` list, you had to decrement `i` as well so you would not miss an entry.